# Haskell Data.Vector, huge memory leak

Tags: haskell, data-structures, memory-leaks, sdl

I am trying to make a basic 2D engine with haskell and the SDL1.2 bindings (for fun, I am just learning).
Ideally the world is to be procedurally generated, chunk by chunk, allowing free exploration.

Right now my chunk is composed of 200*200 tiles which I represent using a type:

`Mat [Tile] = Vec.Vector (Vec.Vector [Tile])`

and these functions:

```
fromMat :: [[a]] ->  Mat a
fromMat xs = Vec.fromList [Vec.fromList xs' | xs' <- xs]

(§) :: Mat a -> (Int, Int) -> a
v § (r, c) = (v Vec.! r) Vec.! c
```

I am using cyclic list of tiles in order to allow for sprite animation, and later for dynamic behaviour.

Each frame of the game loop, the program reads the part of the vector relevant to the current camera position, display the corresponding tiles and return a new vector in which every of these cyclic lists has been replaced by it's tail.

Here is the code responsible for this:

```
applyTileMat :: Chunk -> SDL.Surface -> SDL.Surface -> IO Chunk
applyTileMat ch src dest = 
  let m = chLand $! ch
      (x,y) = chPos ch
      wid = Vec.length (m Vec.! 0) - 1
      hei = (Vec.length m) - 1
      (canW,canH) = canvasSize ch in

  do sequence $ [ applyTile (head (m § (i,j))) (32*(j-x), 32*(i-y)) src dest | i <- [y..(y+canH)], j <- [x..(x+canW)]]
     m' <-sequence $ [sequence [(return $! tail (m § (i,j))) | j <- [0..wid]] | i <- [0..hei]] --weird :P
     return ch { chLand = fromMat m' }
```

the first sequence does the display part, the second one returns the new vector m'.

At first I was using the following comprehension to get m'

```
let !m' = [id $! [(tail $! (m § (i,j))) | j <- [0..wid]] | i <- [0..hei]]
```

but doing so results in ever increasing memory usage. I think it has to do with lazy evaluation preventing the data to be properly garbage collected, but I don't really understand why.

In this particular case, it doesn't really mater since I have to look at the whole vector. But I don't know how I should do if I wanted to only "update" part of my chunk each frame, thus making a new chunk with only part of the data from the previous one.

I am probably not using Data.Vector the way it's intended, but it's the simplest data structure I found with O(n) random access.

The whole code is there:
https://github.com/eniac314/wizzard/blob/master/tiler.hs

Comment: shot in the dark, but did you test the same with Data.Vector.Unboxed?

Comment: @hasufell OP's storing `[Tile]`-s in the vector, which can't be unboxed.

Comment: yes I thought about it but like András said it seems I can only store basic types with unboxed vectors.

Comment: Tip that may or may not help: use `Vector [Tile]` instead of `Vector (Vector [Tile])`. You can index it as though it was 2D. You could also use `Vec.map` and `Vec.mapM` for update instead of indexing, `Vec.fromList` and `sequence`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is indeed that vectors are lazy in the elements. First, let's look at why your example doesn't work.

```
let !m' = [id $! [(tail $! (m § (i,j))) | j <- [0..wid]] | i <- [0..hei]]
```

The bang pattern in `!m` doesn't do much. All `!` does is ensure that a variable is a constructor or a lambda, instead of a function application. Here `!m` can be discerned to be either an `[]` or a `(:)` without evaluating any elements. Similarly, the `įd $!`-s don't force any actual elements of the inner lists.

```
return ch { chLand = fromMat m' }
```

`fromMat` is the next culprit. `fromMat` doesn't force the inner vectors, and also doesn't force the elements. As a result, references to old vectors stick around in the thunks indefinitely.

Often the correct solution is to import `Control.DeepSeq`, and use `force` or `$!!` to fully evaluate vectors. Unfortunately, we can't do that here because of the cyclic lists (trying to force one results in an infinite loop).

What we really need is a function that brings all the elements of a vector to weak head normal form:

```
whnfElements :: Vector a -> Vector a
whnfElements v = V.foldl' (flip seq) () v `seq` v
```

We can use this to define a strict `map` for vectors:

```
vmap' :: (a -> b) -> Vector a -> Vector b
vmap' f = whnfElements . V.map f
```

Now updating becomes:

```
update :: Mat [Tile] -> Mat [Tile]
update = (vmap' . vmap') tail
```

Comment: Brilliant, that did it! But what would happen if I only needed to look at a small part of the current vector to construct the next one? would the necessity to reduce all the élements to WHNF force me to go through the whole vector?

Comment: If you're using vectors, then the whole vector must be copied on every update anyway. So whnf-ing all the elements doesn't add much overhead, and it can't be skipped either, because skipping it for any single element brings back the memory leak.

Comment: If you want efficient update, you have to use something else than vectors. `Data.IntMap` or `Data.HashMap` are likely the fastest for this, but note that they have considerable space-time overheads. Perhaps you could try a `Map` containing vector blocks of some size (16-32); with that you get much better space efficiency. You must copy at least one whole block on every update, but it's a a bounded and possibly tolerable amount, unlike with vectors.

Comment: This time I defined the functions `vImap' f = whnfElements.Vec.imap f` and `update m (i,j,v) = vImap' (\k v' -> if k == i
                                    then vImap' (\l v'' -> if l == j then v else v'') v'
                                    else v') m ` in order to allow update based on indexing. Using it brings back the memory leak, even though I used @ András `whnfElements` in the definition of vImap'.  I don't see where the thunks are accumulating this time.

Comment: Look at the `else v'` part. You're not doing `whnfElement` there.

Comment: BTW, I think you should use `Vector [Tile]` instead of `Vector (Vector [Tile])`. It's faster, smaller and more convenient with library functions.

Comment: Ok, It's working again, lazy evaluation is hurting my brain! :) I am going to try to switch to Vector [Tile]. Thank you for your help!